# sort coordinates by x value

Tags: c++

I have following code:

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
struct Point
{
  int x, y;
};
bool Sort(struct Point& a,struct  Point& b){
  return a.x<b.x;
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  vector<Point>a;
  for (int i=0;i<10;i++){
    cin>>a[i].x>>a[i].y;
  }
  sort(a,10,Sort);
  system("PAUSE");
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

but it seems wrong. Can you please tell me the correct form of the sort function to use?

Comment: By "it seems wrong" do you perhaps mean "it doesn't compile?"

Comment: That `Sort()` function of yours is a real misnomer, since it doesn't sort at all. Instead it is _used_ by the sorting function to __compare__ elements. Something like `CompareByX()` might be more appropriate.

Answer (score 4):

You should call it like that:

```
sort( a.begin(), a.end(), Sort);
```

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify the start and end iterator for the sort function. This can be done by using `a.begin()` and `a.end()` functions.

```
std::sort( a.begin(), a.end(), Sort);
```

Also,
The predicate defn' should be:

```
bool Sort(const Point& a,const Point& b) const
```

{

Comment: it may be necessary to either move the `Sort()` method outside the class (make it global), or make it a static method of the class, or make a function object containing a `bool operator()(const Point& a, const Point& b) {...}`. the stl `sort` can take either a function pointer (which could be global function or static member function) or a function object, but not a instance member function.

Comment: @rwong: It was actually a global function, but the formatting was quite appalling and it looked like a class method. I've just fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution in your case is using **list** instead of **vector** and overloading **operator <**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <list>

struct Point
{
    int x, y;

    bool operator<( const Point & p )
    { return this->x < p.x; }
};

void print( Point p )
{
    std::cout << "Point (x,y): (" << p.x <<", " << p.y << ")" << std::endl;
}

// just for example
bool Reverse( const Point &p1, const Point &p2 )
{ return p1.x > p2.x; }

int main( )
{
    std::list<Point> a;

    for( int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) 
    {
        Point p;
        std::cin >> p.x >> p.y;
        a.push_back( p );
    }

    a.sort( );
    std::for_each( a.begin( ), a.end( ), print );

    std::cout << std::endl;

    a.sort( Reverse );
    std::for_each( a.begin( ), a.end( ), print );
}
```

std::list provides specialized algorithms unique to linked lists, such as splicing, sorting, and in-place reversal.

Comment: If you're up to sort your data frequently, a list is undoubtly advantageous. Even more for big bunch of data.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be something like this:

```
static bool Sort(const Point& a, const Point& b) {
    return a.x<b.x;
}
```

Not quite. See comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Point
{
  int x, y;
};

bool PCompare(const struct Point& a, const struct Point& b) {

    if(a.y < b.y)
        return true;
    if(a.y > b.y)
        return false;
    return a.x<b.x;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  vector<Point> a;
  for (int i=0;i<10;i++) {
      Point p ;
    cin>>p.x>>p.y;
    a.push_back(p);
  }

  sort(a.begin(), a.end(), PCompare);
  system("PAUSE");
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```